# Override Inline Style with 11 Stacked IDs and a class

Tags: html, css

So, if an inline style has a css specificity of 1000 and IDs have a specificity of 100, stacking 11 ID's with a class should override the inline style without using the !important declaration.

So, why doesn't this work? I thought CSS had a point system where the highest number wins.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <style>
        #a > #b > #c > #d > #e > #f > #g > #h > #i > #j > #k > div.foo {
            background-color: red;
        }


    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
      <div id="a">
          <div id="b">
              <div id="c">
                  <div id="d">
                      <div id="e">
                          <div id="f">
                              <div id="g">
                                  <div id="h">
                                      <div id="i">
                                          <div id="j">
                                              <div id="k">
                                                  <div style="background-color: blue;" class="foo">FOOOO</div>
                                              </div>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No...because inline styling comes last so it wins.

Comment: Indeed - I would not focus on CSS specificity point values, as they aren't always intuitive.

Comment: So, the CSS specificity algorithm doesn't sum all the point attributes where

inline-style: 1000
id: 100
class: 10
element: 1

And then sort the added ones? It's basically sorted on 4 different buckets of inline, id, class then element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No...because inline styling comes last in the 'cascade" and so it wins  regardless of the specificity.

It can only be overriden by adding `!important`.

In fact that's all you'd need.

```css
 div.foo {
   background-color: red !important;
 }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="a">
    <div id="b">
      <div id="c">
        <div id="d">
          <div id="e">
            <div id="f">
              <div id="g">
                <div id="h">
                  <div id="i">
                    <div id="j">
                      <div id="k">
                        <div style="background-color: blue;" class="foo">FOOOO</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Got it. So the algorithm itself sorts cascading on the individual selectors. It doesn't sort by adding the point values of the selectors and then sorting those. Therefore a million classes can never override an ID.

Comment: Essentially, yes. See this - https://jsfiddle.net/unnoyk65/1/

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't override inline CSS with ID's. However you could do something like this:

```
div[style] {
background-color: yellow !important;
}
```